# Contradiction / Law of E.M question in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $ab$ is even, then either $a$ is even or $b$ is even (or both).

I need to make a pure contradiction proof, and a pure law of excluded middle proof

**Contradiction:**

"Suppose a, b ∈ Z and ab is even, then both a and b are odd", derive a contradiction

Law of excluded middle:

I could either do a direct proof using cases, and since it is true, by excluded middle it can't be false?

Or use the same proposition in the contradiction argument, and get that it is false, therefore the original statement is true.

Can someone tell or suggest me correct approaches?

Comment: Let $ab$ even. **Assume** that both $a$ and $b$ are odd. Then $ab$ is odd, since the product of odd numbers is odd. This is a contradiction, since $ab$ was assumed to be even.

Comment: ok that wraps up contradiction, but Im still confused about what a pure law of excluded middle proof looks like

Comment: I’m a bit confused by the question, to be honest. Usually the entire point of a contradiction proof is that we use double negation elimination, which is equivalent to the law of the excluded middle. (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Double_Negation_Elimination_implies_Law_of_Excluded_Middle) As far as I know, a “contradiction proof” *is* a proof using LEM, as far as classical logic goes. At the very least, you can always take any proof in terms of LEM and re-express it in terms of double negation elimination (contradiction) and vice-versa. I don’t get it.

Comment: IMO, you have to provide **two** proofs : the **first** one by contradiction : $ab$ even abd assume (for contra) that both $a$ and $b$ are odd.

Comment: The **second** one sound more "strange" : pure LEM proof. It may mean : use the fact that "either $a$ is even of $a$ is **not** even". If $a$ is even, then "either $a$ is even or $b$ is even" holds. Then, consider the case : $a$ is **not** even. This means $a=2k+1$ for some $k$ but $ab=2l=(2k+1)b$, for some $l$.

Comment: Having said that, I agree with the first comemnt above : we are running in a circle... How to prove that $ab$ even with $a$ odd implies $b$ even ? We have to know already that odd times odd is odd.

Answer (score 1):

If both $a$ and $b$ are odd then $a=2k+1$and $b =2l+1$

$$ab=(2k+1)(2l+1)=4kl+2(k+l)+1$$

Which is an odd integer contrary to the assumption that the product was even.

Answer (score 0):

Contradiction:

Original proposition is the way to go, thanks guys.

For pure LEM, goes as follows -

Need to use LEM as part of proof, not the whole argument structure.

So just case on either a is even or a is odd, as there is no in-between, that's where LEM comes in.

If a is even, then done.

If a is odd, then just derive that b is even. To do that, use definition of odds and evens.

As follows: If ab is even, and a is odd, by definition of evens and odds, then

I can write "2q = (2k + 1) b" where q and k are integers. This is restating "ab = ab", but I replace one side with 2q, since ab is even, and a as 2k+1, since it is odd.

Then, I distribute, so I have "2q = 2kb + b", rearrange and factor to get:

"2(q-kb) = b", and since (q-kb) ∈ ℤ. then by definition, b is even.

So we show the second assumption to be also true, so the overall proposition is true. 
The big takeaway is that LEM was used as part, not whole of proof.